# Save TreeView to XML and load it from XML in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, treeview, xmldataprovider

I found some questions and answers here about how to save treeview to xml and load it from xml  by using WPF/C#. However, using xmldataprovider, none of them works, and using AppendChild, exporttoxml works but there is no way to import it from xml saved.

In case of xmldataprovider, it has the schema in XAML so it doesn't seem to allow the user to update treeview once xml is loaded on the treeview.

I am looking for a way which can save treeview to xml and load it from xml saved as well as can allow the user to modify the treeview after the xml is loaded onto treeview.

Does any know how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to save just the data or the TreeView control itself?

Comment: title and data. For example, if node name is "Menu 1" and its value is "menu_1.xaml", xml should contain both.

Comment: so far what I've figured out is that there are two ways for this; 1. data binding by xmldataprovider 2. converting xml to XDocument. But I am not sure which one of both is the best and the simplest way.